# What is meant by "..waxing literary.."?

Tags: word-usage

An excerpt:

> "Here you will find the truly erudite waxing literary on a recently
>   published novel or book."

'erudite' means learned, pedantic, bookish. The meaning of the sentence is clear in that the context is being referred to as a place to find good and insightful text (or whatever related literature). What purpose is the adjective 'waxing' serving here?

Comment: [Dictionary definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/wax#wax-2__10)

Comment: You have parsed the sentence wrong; erudite—noun; waxing—verb; literary—adjective complement modifying *erudite*. The meaning is: here you will find erudite people talking about books.

Comment: That's right @PeterShor. That explains that I did not get the usage of the word waxing: the doubt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, "waxing" is used as a verb to indicate an increasingly literary mindset or mode of speech (its antonym is "waning," or decreasing). A more commonly-used idiom is "waxing poetic." These terms are also used to describe the moon's transition from new to full (waxing) and back (waning).

Comment: "Waning literary" and its like are seldom used, and will sound odd to native speakers.